# Twisted and "'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_library_init'"

Tags: openssl, twisted, twisted.internet

I try to run below command:

```
python millionaires.py --ssl player-1.ini
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "millionaires.py", line 152, in <module>
pre_runtime = create_runtime(id, players, 1, options, Toft05Runtime)
File "/home/user/opt/lib/python/viff/runtime.py", line 1091, in create_runtime
ctx_factory = SSLContextFactory(id)
File "/home/user/opt/lib/python/viff/runtime.py", line 1071, in __init__
SSL.SSL_library_init()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_library_init'
```

also I have these errors, too.

```
Using SSL

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "benchmark.py", line 209, in <module>
options, runtime_class)
File "/home/user/opt/lib/python/viff/runtime.py", line 1090, in create_runtime
ctx_factory = SSLContextFactory(id)
File "/home/user/opt/lib/python/viff/runtime.py", line 1071, in __init__
ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv3_METHOD)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 478, in __init__
_raise_current_error()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 48, in exception_from_error_queue
raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_new', 'null ssl method passed')]
```

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: What version of OpenSSL? I believe 1.1.0 removed `SSL_library_init` in favor of `OPENSSL_init_ssl`. Also see [Library Initialization](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: openssl version = 
OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016